# Ubuntu 19.10 not logging in

Tags: nvidia, login, 19.10

In Ubuntu 19.10 after changing the settings for Nvidia mx130, won't even log in. After typing the password it just freezes in a purple screen and mouse doesn't work. That happens to both xorg and Ubuntu on wayland

Comment: Reconfigure xorg.conf and create xorg.conf.d also to detect mouse,keyboard,lininput and server layout

Comment: You could try the recovery mode and check the logs. Most of the time Ctrl+Alt+F2-6 can give you a console. I used apt remove to uninstall the nvidia driver for now